# Use Selector() with arguments

Tags: ios, swift

How do I pass arguments to the function `switchCard`?

```
let singleTap1 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "switchCard:")
```

This is the function:

```
func switchCard(card: Int, withCard: Int) {
    print(card)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The function that catches the tap gesture should be like that:

```
let singleTap1 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "switchCard:")

func switchCard(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    //do your works here
    //tapped view : recognizer.view
    //tap state   : recognizer.state
    //see: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/index.html  for more info
}
```

Comment: and how do i pass arguments to it?

Comment: For which reasons that you want to pass arguments to it? Normally, the call-back of gesture give you only the gesture recognizer that help you identifier the gesture. Then, it's up to you that decide your actions.

Comment: Inside the method that is called by the gesture recognizer you can determine what has been tapped and then take necessary steps.

Comment: how do i determine what has been tapped?

Comment: You can use **locationInView(_ view: UIView?) -> CGPoint** UIGestureRecognizer´s method to compare the UIView source. If it returns something different of nil you will have a valid touch. You can find out more here: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/cl/c:objc(cs)UIGestureRecognizer

Answer (score 0):

You can use tag in view you clicked:

```
yourView.tag = 12345
let singleTap1 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "switchCard:")
yourView.addGestureRecognizer(singleTap1)

func switchCard(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

     let view: UIView = recognizer.view
     let id = view.tag   // = 12345

    //do your works here
}
```

Comment: and how do i pass an argument containing the card to switch with?

Answer (score 0):

check this below code and its working:

```
func switchCard(card: Int, withCard card1: Int) {
    print(card)
}
let singleTap1 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "switchCard:withCard:")
```